# What is the partition type ('t' command) in fdisk good for?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, fdisk

I can't understand the difference between the filesystem specified using `fdisk`'s command line interface with `t`. And the one used to format it later using say `mkefs`.

Why do we need to specify it twice?

1. Say I launch an fdisk session using `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb1`
2. Now, I create a partition using the `n` command.
3. Then I change the file system type using the `t` command.
4. After that, I still have to format the partition and specify the file system again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of partition type and filesystem type?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230930/whats-the-difference-of-partition-type-and-filesystem-type)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to change the partition type like linux to Fat,

In this case, you have use the t command to change the partition type,like below,

```
Device         Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
**/dev/mmcblk0p1       8096   90111   82016   40M 83 Linux**
/dev/mmcblk0p2      90112 7634943 7544832  3.6G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 1
Hex code (type L to list all codes): c

Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'W95 FAT32 (LBA)'.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3.7 GiB, 3909091328 bytes, 7634944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1d437f06

Device         Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
**/dev/mmcblk0p1       8096   90111   82016   40M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)**
/dev/mmcblk0p2      90112 7634943 7544832  3.6G 83 Linux
```

Note: I have changed the first partition to FAT32 from linux using t command to set the respective HEX code for that.

Answer (score 0):

What you specify with the `t` command of `fdisk` is the **partition type**. This is not related to the **filesystem** that is inside that partition.

The *partition type* is stored in the *partition table* and is a hint for the BIOS/EFI firmware or the OS of the content of the partition.  I guess only *Windows* used to use it.

But this is not related of the *filesystem* you later create on that partition.

You could try to create an *ext4* partition on a **W95 FAT32** labeled partition and linux will be fine with it. This is not recommended but nothing forbids you to do so.